# What's the difference between Range.Item and Range.Cells?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, in the code below, `Item` and `Cells` can be used interchangeably:

```
Dim rRange As Range
Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

With rRange
    Debug.Print .Item(1, 1).Value   ' Outputs value of "A1"
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1).Value  ' Outputs value of "A1"

    Debug.Print .Item(2, 1).Value   ' Outputs value of "A2"
    Debug.Print .Cells(2, 1).Value  ' Outputs value of "A2"
End With
```

---

In the developer reference, they are defined as:

[**Range.Item Property (Excel)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273(v=office.15).aspx)

> Returns a Range object that represents a range at an offset to the
>   specified range.

~

[**Range.Cells Property (Excel)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096(v=office.15).aspx)

> Returns a Range object that represents the cells in the specified range.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Because the Item property is the default property for the Range object, you can specify the row and column index immediately after the Cells keyword.

From that remark, does it mean that `Cells(1, 1)` is actually a short for `Cells.Item(1, 1)`? Thus `Cells(1, 1)` is actually equivalent to `Item(1, 1)`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to understand this is via the below example

When `.Item` and `.Cells` are used with respect to a range then, YES, they are same. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:C10")

    With rRange
        Debug.Print .Item(1, 3).Address '<~~ $D$1
        Debug.Print .Cells(1, 3).Address '<~~ $D$1
    End With
End Sub
```

In the above they both depict the address of the cell in that `Range`

They are different when `Cells()` is used independently of a range.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rRange As Range
    Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:C10")

    With rRange
        Debug.Print .Item(1, 3).Address  '<~~ $D$1
        '~~> DOT before Cells missing
        Debug.Print Cells(1, 3).Address  '<~~ $C$1
    End With
End Sub
```

In the above `.Item` depicts the address of the cell in that `Range`, where as `Cells` depicts the address of the cell in the `ActiveSheet`

Comment: To add to the confusion `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1, 3).Address` is $C$1. I try to keep it straight by thinking of `Item` as always being part of a collection so `ActiveSheet.Item(1, 3)` is not valid while `ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1, 3)` is.

Comment: True. `.Item` is to be used with a range object whereas cells can be used independently as well :)

Comment: Just to be clear, Item can be used with any... well "item" in any Collection, not just for the Range Collection.

Comment: @Tim: I am sure OP is not asking about those :) He wants to know about `Range.Item`.

Comment: True, but if you know that Item is a generic member of any collection, then you can better understand why it appears to be a duplicate of the Cell in this context :)

Comment: @Tip: Oh that's what you meant :)

Comment: So the only use of `Cells` is being able to refer to all cells in the `ActiveSheet`? In other cases, I can even use something like `Range("A1:B2")(2)`!

Answer (score -1):

I can see no use of the Cells Property other than for referring to all the cells in a Worksheet.
I would put it like this, ( based on my experiments and research) :

The Cells Property returns a Range Object  containing all the cells of the Object to which it is applied. 
For the case of a Worksheet it is clearly useful so as to be able to use all the Properties of the Range Object on the entire Worksheet.
For the case of a Range Object I am not sure if it has any use. I cannot find, for example, any extra Property that I cannot get from the Range Object's Properties without first applying the Cells Property to that Range Object

I am wondering if some of its use in code  has just “*crept in*” over the years. For example , I believe this type of code line is one possible Explicit way to refer to  the Range Object of the second cell in a worksheet using the Range Object Item Property
Ws.Range("A1").Areas.Item(1).Item(1, 2)
Along the lines of what feelthhis said,  I can rely on  the implied implicit of first Area and Default Property of Item to rewrite that code line thus:
Ws.Range("A1")(1, 2)

If I drop in a  Cells Property , I do no harm
Ws.Range("A1").Cells(1, 2)

But I would suggest: 
_(i) use of Cells here is totally redundant
_(ii) I am still using here the Range Item Property.
_(iii) There is no Cells Item Property
_(iv) A code part like this Cells(1, 2) has “*crept in*” as a so called “*Cells Property that  will accept one or two arguments..*......”..and/ or ...”*cells has a Item Property..*.”...etc... ,. I think those statements  may be incorrect.
 I think the Cells Property has no argument. 
( I am not too sure if Cells  may have an Item Property. I am not a computing professional but experts have told me that intellisense offering it , or Microsoft Help suggesting it is no guarantee that it exists. I expect there is no Cells Item Property)

In all case a code part like this, Cells(1, 2),  is explained as follows:
 Cells is returning a Range Object. That Range Object is having its default Property, the Range Object Item Property applied to it. Unless I am using Cells independently to a Range, I should probably omit it. 
I suggest this as,  in this case, I am not being explicit. Rather I am contributing to a, possibly false, idea   that I can refer to a Range Object via a _..
_..  “*Cells(_argument/s_) type*”  Property, .. which possibly does not exist.

Alan

Comment: @Comintern: Hi Comintern, thanks for the comment. Sorry I don’t see the relevance to the question or my answer. ( FWIW I deplore the use of default properties and unqualified references and work hard to encourage others not to use them. But that is not the issue here)

Comment: Just to clarify: I am suggesting an explanation of how the so called Cells(r, c) type Property comes about. The explanation is partly based on considering the common use of defaults. The pros and cons of using default properties and unqualified references is not the issue here.