# Trying to understand the difference between the use of Item property and Cells property on a Range object

Tags: excel, vba

I understand:

- `Range.Item` *returns a Range object that represents a range at an offset to the specified range*.
- `Range.Cells` *returns a Range object that represents the cells in the specified range*.

However, the confusion sets in when I read that *"Item is a default property of the `Range` object"*.

This leads me to ask:

Is `Range("A1:D5").Cells(1,1)` really a simplified version of
`Range("A1:D5").Cells.Item(1,1)`?

And why not just use `Range("A1:D5").Item(1,1)` in any case?

Why does it seem that VBA programmers use the `Cells` property to reference ranges instead of the `Item` property? Is it "best practice" to just omit the `Item` default property in favor of `Cells`?

Comment: have a look at [SO: Range() vs Cells() vs Range.Cells()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093274/range-vs-cells-vs-range-cells) as there are answers on there that may help

Comment: also see [Understanding Excel Cells vs. Range Functions in VBA](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/excel-cells-vs-range-functions-vba/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [SO: Range() vs Cells() vs Range.Cells()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093274/range-vs-cells-vs-range-cells)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Range.Item and Range.Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879619/whats-the-difference-between-range-item-and-range-cells)

Comment: Thanks, everyone, but none of the articles clarified it for me. Is there anyone who can just answer the questions I asked with Yes or No - and then explain? LOL

Comment: No. `Range.Item(x, y)` returns a `Variant`. If you need a `Range`, use `Cells` so it doesn't need to be un-boxed into an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Range` is a *class*. Classes are *blueprints* for *objects* - an object is an *instance* of a class.

Now, classes in VBA can have a *default property*. If you export a class module, you can give them *member attributes*. The `VB_UserMemId` attribute, with a value of `0`, identifies a member as that class' *default member* - you can't edit member attributes directly in the VBE, but you can export the module, add the attribute, and re-import the module into the project.

A *default property* might look something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private mFoo As Bar

Public Property Get Foo() As Bar
    Attribute Foo.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Foo = mFoo
End Property
```

There are a number of possible `VB_UserMemId` values you can use, but only one member of a class can have any given value - `0` makes it that class' default member.

Default members allow you to write *implicit code* - whether that's a good thing or not is a judgement call.

For example when you want to access the item at index `i` of a `Collection`, you can do this:

```
foo = myCollection.Item(i)
```

But since `Item` is the *default property* of the `Collection` class, you can also do this:

```
foo = myCollection(i)
```

And the result is exactly the same.

The `Range` class is... a *special* animal. If you look at its definition in the *Object Browser*, you'll find that its *default property* is a hidden property named `_Default`, which is commonly inferred to return `Range.Value` - because this implicit default member call:

```
foo = Sheet1.Range("A1")
```

Is equivalent to this explicit code:

```
foo = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
```

The `Item` property of the `Range` class is *not* the default member. However if you look at the definition of that hidden `_Default` property, you'll see that it accepts two optional parameters:

[image: Property _Default({RowIndex},{ColumnIndex})]

So this is also legal:

```
foo = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")(1)
```

And equivalent to this:

```
foo = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Item(1).Value
```

Basically, the `Range` class' default property is implemented in such a way that it does one thing if no parameters are specified (gives you the `Value`.. which itself returns either the cell's value, or a 2D variant array if the range contains multiple cells), and another thing if parameters *are* specified (gives you the `Item` at the specified row/column within that range).

So this is why `Range("A1:A10").Cells` (without parameters) is redundant: it yields the exact same cells as `Range("A1:A10")` does.

The `Cells` property isn't parameterized:

[image: Property Cells As Range]

So VBA programmers invoking `Range.Cells` with parameters, are in fact invoking `Range._Default` with these parameters, against the range returned by `Cells`... which means `Range("A1:A10").Cells(1)` is effectively `Range("A1:A10").Cells.Item(1)`... which involves a redundant call to `Cells`.

The parameterized `Cells[._Default][.Item](1)` syntax is therefore a mere convenience; it's mostly a readability thing... and then there's *IntelliSense*: `Item` returns a `Variant`, which means you don't get that nice little dropdown of available members when you type the `.` dot/dereferencing operator after it (the call is "late-bound", i.e. the type involved is resolved at run-time) - but you do when you invoke `Cells`, because `Cells` returns an early-bound `Range` object (i.e. resolved at compile-time).

Best-practice is to *write code that does what it says, and says what it does* - so you will *generally* want to *avoid* implicit default member calls. However in the case of a `Range` this conflicts with another best-practice, i.e. *write compile-time validated, early-bound code whenever possible* - using `Cells` instead of `Item` gives you that.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this wonderful explanation. I get it! Mathieu, you rock. You answered my last question too.^^

Comment: foo = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")(1) - is that not supposed to have a period before (1)?

Comment: @GeekyFreaky no, because the dot (aka dereferencing oeprator) would warrant an explicit member call immediately after it. Since the member call is implicit, there's no dot. With the dot that would be `Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Item(1)`, or `.Cells(1)`. `Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")` returns a `Range` object, so you can legally make an implicit default member call directly against it. Now whether that's a good idea is another story ;-)